# Difficulty deploying database with my iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an application that needs a database. The application is running fine in the simulator. But when i try to deploy it onto the iphone then it gives me the error that 'no such table animal'. Where is the problem? I am providing the code for better understanding

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AnimalDatabase.sql"];


sqlite3 *database;


if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
{

    const char *sqlStatement = "insert into animal (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        //NSLog(filePath);
        sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 1, 12);
        //NSLog(@"A");
        sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 2, [@"abc" UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);        
        //NSLog(@"B");
        if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE )
        {
            //NSLog(@"C");
            NSLog( @"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
        }
        else
        {
            //NSLog(@"D");
            NSLog( @"Insert into row id = %d", sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating insert statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error Occured");
}
sqlite3_close(database);
[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to look at what is being transfered to your iPhone.  I had issues with this, there are some strange issues around how the database is created or not created on the actual iPhone.  I think what is happening in your case is that no database is being transfered, and then your call to

```
sqlite3_open
```

is actually creating the database so you don't receive an error until you call a select statement.

Check your documentation on where to place the db in your resources to ensure it is copied to your iPhone when building.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason is that the AnimalDatabase.sql file doesn't exist so there is no Animal table to insert into.

Comment: But i will disagree with you in that. Because if the animal database is not present then how can the program run on simulator?

Comment: This could well be the issue. From what I can remember there is a difference between how the simulator handles case sensitivity of files to the way the phone handles sensitivity